# apache userdir - home folder permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

I have added the userdir module with

```
a2enmod userdir
```

I have configured the following in the sites-available/example.conf

```
UserDir disabled
UserDir enabled lazaro
UserDir www
```

Then I have created a file

```
/home/lazaro/www/index.html
```

with the following permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx 5 webdesigner www-data 4,0K Ago 25 11:05 www
-rwxrwxrwx 1 webdesigner www-data 350 Ago 25 11:01 index.html
```

When I try to access

```
http://www.example.com/~lazaro/index.html
```

I get

```
You don't have permission to access /~lazaro/index.html on this server.
```

ps aux | grep apache

```
myself   29035  0.0  0.0  11780  2216 pts/1    S+   20:57   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
root     29172  0.0  0.1  73392  4196 ?        Ss   11:36   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29175  0.0  0.1 493764  6268 ?        Sl   11:36   0:07 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29176  0.0  0.1 1935956 7516 ?        Sl   11:36   0:06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common for user directories to have restrictive permissions such as `700` or `750`.  This can prevent the web server from accessing its sub directories.  Allowing others to access known files can be done by changing this to `701` or `751`.  Even less restrictive would be to use `755`.

The user directory is usually the `~/public_html` directory for the user.  Try creating this directory and putting your files in it.

Ordering of options is often important. Try:

```
UserDir www
UserDir enabled lazaro
UserDir disabled
```

These options may also work:

```
UserDir www lazaro
UserDir disabled
```

Access to the `/home` may be covered by restrictions on `/`.  You may also need to allow access to the directory.  Review the documentation to determine if they are appropriate for your requirements.

```
<Directory /home/lazaro/www>
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
        Require all granted
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
        Require all denied
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

Your apache error log may explain which particular restrictions are being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768976/204785

## Solution 1: (Risky - Refer [Solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768976/204785))

Add the apache2 user (in my case `www-data`), to the logged in user group. This way `www-data` has access to everything user `/home/joe`.

`adduser www-data joe`

Also all files under `public_html` must have `rx` permissions for the group.

`chmod -R g+rw /home/joe/public_html`

## Solution 2:

Allow any `other` to search(`x`) `/home/joe`

`chmod o+x /home/joe`

Also all files under `public_html` must be accessible by `others` for `rx` permissions.

`chmod -R o+rw /home/joe/public_html`